# restoring a EC2 snapshot on RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to restore our database snapshot on ec2 directly on RDS as our database is very big ?

If not can we restore using csv files. ?

Comment: The phrase *"restore our database snapshot on ec2 directly on RDS"* does not really explain what you are trying to do.  Please edit the question to clarify *exactly* what you are trying to do, and why.

Comment: It is advisable to use mysqldump for transporting data since it will escape your data correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to restore an EC2 snapshot to RDS.

It is possible, though not necessarily advisable, depending on the circumstances, to restore an EC2 snapshot to another server.